# jQueryUI modal dialog does not show close button (x)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, dialog

I'm  using a jQuery modal dialog in my ASP .NET MVC 3 application. It works fine except for that there is no close button showing in the top right corner. How can I add this?

```
$("#dialog-modal").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In the upper right corner of the dialog, mouse over where the button *should* be, and see rather or not you get some effect (the button hover).  Try clicking it and seeing if it closes.  If it does close, then you're just missing your image sprites that came with your package download.

Comment: Found this question and that was my issue, too. Also note that the native directory for this is `/css/images/` and not `/root/images/` like the rest of your images might be.

Comment: And how do I fix this?

Answer (score 196):

Another possibility is that you have the bootstrap library.  Some version of bootstrap and jquery-ui have conflict with the .button() method, and if your bootstrap.js is placed after jquery-ui.js, the bootstrap .button() overrides your jquery button and the jquery-ui 'X' image would then not show up.

see here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/6094

This works (close box visible):

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

This causes the issue:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This one pointed out the solution to me: Load first bootstrap and then jqueryUI. Cheers.

Comment: Lovely - note that when including jQuery, Bootstrap **and** jQuery UI, you need to include them in that order (jQuery 1st, Bootstrap 2nd, UI 3rd)

Comment: The answer can mess up some of bootstrap's functionality though - so if you're in a bind - try a little hack with css for the button class: .ui-dialog-titlebar-close:after {
  content: 'X';
  font-weight:bold;
}

Comment: This is one sort of answer that makes SO great - it might not be especially detailed or "expert", but you won't find it in a book.

Comment: To add a little more detail to his excellent answer: first load the jquery library, next the bootstrap library and css, and then the jquery UI library and jquery UI css file. example:  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: You can also run $.fn.button.noConflict() just before you call your dialog and everything should work fine!

Comment: `$.fn.button.noConflict()` should be the answer.

Comment: @Ross can you explain which features of bootstrap are affected by this answer.

Answer (score 40):

I had this problem and was able to resolve it with the declaration below.

```
$.fn.bootstrapBtn = $.fn.button.noConflict();
```

Comment: This is the issue when using bootstrap and jqueryui together.  Best solution.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ $.fn.bootstrapBtn = $.fn.button.noConflict();}   This resolved the conflict and resolved all other conflicts in the jQuery dialog as well.

Comment: switching jquery ui and bootstrap creates other issue. it worked perfectly (Y)

Comment: Strangely, the `noConflict()` function seems self-consuming (I have `function (){return a.fn.button=d,this}`). That is, after calling, it's `undefined`. To code defensively, I put the `noConflict` call in the function opening a jQuery dialog, so I needed to check `if ($.fn.button.noConflict) {...` before executing `noConflict`.

Comment: Do you know why I get the error "$.fn.button.noConflict is not a function" when I try your suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

**Pure CSS Workaround:**

I was using both bootstrap and jQuery UI and changing the order of adding the scripts broke some other objects. I ended up using pure CSS workaround:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
  background: url("http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png") repeat scroll -93px -128px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: medium none;
}
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close:hover {
  background: url("http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png") repeat scroll -93px -128px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: In my humble opinion, this is the cleanest and most elegant solution

Answer (score 12):

While the op does not explicitly state they are using jquery ui and bootstrap together, an identical problem happens if you do. You can resolve the problem by loading bootstrap (js) before jquery ui (js). However, that will cause problems with button state colors.

The final solution is to either use bootstrap or jquery ui, but not both.  However, a workaround is:

```
    $('<div>dialog content</div>').dialog({
        title: 'Title',
        open: function(){
            var closeBtn = $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close');
            closeBtn.append('<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span><span class="ui-button-text">close</span>');
        }
    });
```

Comment: +1. The only thing is that, not only Bootstrap for some resaon removes those two `span` elements we're appending here, it also removes several classes from the close button as well. So I ended up with slightly modified version, that also **adds missing classes to the close button**: `var closeBtn = $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close'); closeBtn.addClass("ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only");`

Answer (score 6):

Using the principle of the idea user2620505 got result with implementation of addClass:

```
...
open: function(){
    $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').addClass('ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only');
    $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').append('<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span><span class="ui-button-text">close</span>');
}, 
...
```

If English is bad forgive me, I am using Google Translate.

Answer (score 5):

Just check the close button image path in your jquery-ui.css:

```
.ui-icon { 
    width: 16px; 
    height: 16px; 
    background-image: url**(../img/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png)**/*{iconsContent}*/; 
}
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(../img/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png)/*{iconsContent}*/; 
}
.ui-widget-header .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(../img/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png)/*{iconsHeader}*/; 
}
.ui-state-default .ui-icon { 
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png)/*{iconsDefault}*/; 
}
.ui-state-hover .ui-icon, .ui-state-focus .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(../img/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png)/*{iconsHover}*/; 
}
.ui-state-active .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(../img/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png)/*{iconsActive}*/; 
}
```

Correct the path of `icons_222222_256x240.png` and `ui-icons_454545_256x240.png`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue just add this function to the open dialog options and it worked sharm

```
open: function(){
            var closeBtn = $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close');
            closeBtn.append('<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>');
        },
```

and on close event you need to remove that

```
close: function () {
            var closeBtn = $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close');
            closeBtn.html('');}
```

Complete example

```
<div id="deleteDialog" title="Confirm Delete">
 Can you confirm you want to delete this event?
</div> 

$("#deleteDialog").dialog({
                width: 400, height: 200,
                modal: true,
                open: function () {
                    var closeBtn = $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close');
                    closeBtn.append('<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>');
                },
                close: function () {
                    var closeBtn = $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close');
                    closeBtn.html('');
                },
                buttons: {
                    "Confirm": function () {
                        calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
```

Comment: The issue when you using bootstrap with jquery-ui.css

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that the browser could not load the jQueryUI image sprite that contains the X icon. Please use Fiddler, Firebug, or some other that can give you access to the HTTP requests the browser makes to the server and verify the image sprite is loaded successfully.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose there is some conflict with other JS library in your code. Try to force showing the close button:

```
...
open:function () {
  $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").show();
} 
...
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is great answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31045175/3778527
I'm tested with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**The order in which files are added is important!**

Answer (score 2):

Just linking the CSS worked for me.  It may have been missing from my project entirely:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add quotes around the "ok".  That is the text of the button. As it is, the button's text is currently empty (and hence not displayed) because it is trying to resolve the value of that variable.

Modal dialogs aren't meant to be closed in any fashion other than pressing the [ok] or [cancel] buttons.  If you want the [x] in the right hand corner, set modal: false or just remove it altogether.

Comment: That button display fine. In the jquery documentation if i just do $("#dialog").dialog(); with no options there should be a small x in the corner but in my case there is none.

Comment: Wait - isn't the whole point of a modal button that you can't dismiss it without pressing the "OK" button?  the 'modal: true' _should_ be removing that upper right hand corner X by definition.   (Sorry, when I read your question, I was assuming the OK button wasn't showing...)

Comment: Tried with modal:false still no luck

Comment: JqueryUI does not remove the X on the top right corner when it is modal. Look at this example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

Answer (score 0):

a solution can be having the close inside your modal

take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zero7/4DpWn/1/) simple example

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  I was using jquery and jquery-ui.  When I upgraded my versions, the close dialog image no longer appeared.  My problem was that when I unzipped the js package that I downloaded, the directories did not have the execute permission.

So a quick  chmod +x dir-name, and also for the sub-folders, did the trick. Without the execute permission on linux, apache cannot get into the folder.

Answer (score 0):

my solution was to put this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

after all js and style sheet declarations