# Jquery ui dialog buttons not working with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I'm using `jquery 1.11.3` with `jquery-ui 1.11.4` and with `bootstrap 3.3.5` .
All works fine except for standard close `minibutton` on the `jquery ui dialog` upper left corner.
 The symbol "X" doesn't show on the button, nonetheless it works in closing the dialog.
 Examining the markup created for the dialog, it really lacks the part that show the "X" icon.
The dialog is very simple:

```
$('#info').dialog({ autoOpen: true,
     width: 700,
     title: 'User Info',
     position: { my: "center middle", at: "center middle", of: document.body} }
  );
```

I'm aware of the compatibility issues between `jquery-ui` and `bootstrap`, due to name collision on button and tooltip plugins.
So I applied the workaround suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27745464/1233379 but whereas it prevent some javascript error, it not seems to restore full functionality of dialog.

Commenting out bootstrap javascript include tag, jquery-ui works as expected.

Some advice?

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/43hrvy26/

Comment: Can you please provide a demo or a fiddle?

Comment: fiddle url added above

Comment: I see it in the fiddle. which browser?

Comment: btw, I added bootstrap to the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/43hrvy26/1/)

Comment: It's looking good unless I'm missing here something. The `x` symbol is on the small light-gray square on the right side of the dialog. And it also functions right and closing the dialog by clicking it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the order of the JS/CSS inclusion

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
```

Refer https://jsfiddle.net/ZigmaEmpire/43hrvy26/2/

As **jquery-ui.css** comes last the CSS in that file will override any corresponding conflicting CSS in bootstrap, so now you can take advantage of jquery UI CSS instead of bootstrap CSS definitions if any