# Missing some jQuery sprites

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, sprite

I'm using a jQuery UI dialog box, and the **"x" close button is not showing up.** After seeing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681707/jqueryui-modal-dialog-does-not-show-close-button-x) (I'm not using bootstrap) I determined that it was a result of missing images. 
I added the jQueryUI images folder to the *same* location as the jqueryUI css file, but the x button was still not showing. Using `firebug` I saw that jQuery was looking for some images that were not present in the folder (such as ui-icons_c070a0_256x240.png and ui-bg_gloss-wave_35_C070A0_500x100.png).

Where can I find the images that I'm missing from the images folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is it, but give it a try.

jQuery UI dialogs require (1) the jQuery UI css reference, AS WELL AS (2) the jQuery UI code, AS WELL AS (3) plain ol' jQuery.

Equally important, *you need to match the versions*. When the versions do not match (especially when jQUI and the css for jQUI are for different versions), buttons will be out of alignment, borders will be missing, the whole appearance is whacked. You have *version-itis* (note: -itis is Latin suffix for *pain*).

Suggestion:

Remove all references to jQuery/jQuery UI in your code and add the following lines inside the `<head>` tags of your page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

This will give you a version of jQuery / jQueryUI / css that are known to work together. If it works, you can even stick with it.

---

Reference:

[Matching jQuery and jQuery-UI versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370169/matching-jquery-and-jquery-ui-versions)

Comment: Thanks. The issue was that I was using a downloaded version of jQuery and jQuery UI (the most recent versions) to use when testing offline on my computer, so some versions must have been incompatible. The versions your provided worked, but did not support selectmenu so I got the most recent versions from [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/) and then the site worked like a charm.